# How to order get_term_children output by alphabetic order

Tags: terms, get-children

The following creates drop-down lists of my custom taxonomy children, but the order of the output seems to by creation date, not by alphabetical name. I tried adding orderby to the array with no success.

I've read about usort but am not sure how to implement it.

I'd appreciate any help.

```
$term_id = 61;
$taxonomy_name = 'tribe_events_cat';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function taclinkch(x){var y=document.getElementById(x).value;document.location.href=y}</script>";
echo "<form action=''>  <select name='eventcats' id='eventcats'   onchange='taclinkch(this.id)'>";

echo "<option value=''>Select a Topic</option>";

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );

    echo "<option value='" .  get_site_url() . "/events/category/". $term->slug." '>" . $term->name . "</option>";
}

echo "</select></form>";
```

I added this array, which didn't work:

```
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) { 
    $term = get_term_by( 
        'id', 
        $child, 
        $taxonomy_name, 
        array( 
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'hide_empty' => 0
        ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add the orderby? Shouldn't there be a `foreach` or other loop operator on that fifth line down?

Comment: I did it like so: 

'foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
     $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name, array(
  'orderby'    => 'name',
  'hide_empty' => 0) );`

Not sure what you mean about another foreach

Comment: ^^ Please edit that into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Per your comment (and hopefully an edit to the question) :

> I did it like so: `foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) { $term =
>   get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name, array( 'orderby' => 'name',
>   'hide_empty' => 0) );`

Formatted:

```
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) { 
  $term = get_term_by( 
    'id', 
    $child, 
    $taxonomy_name, 
    array( 
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'hide_empty' => 0
    ) 
  );
```

[`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) does not accept an array as the fourth parameter, or in fact any parameter. You can't just make up parameters and expect them to work. You need to look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) and [the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L944).

Besides, [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) is not where the ordering happens. The ordering occurs when you run [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children#Parameters), though that also [does not take a parameter that will order the results](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1007).

You can sort the result set though:

```
$term_id = 61;
$taxonomy_name = 'tribe_events_cat';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
$children = array();
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
  $children[$term->name] = $term;
}
ksort($children);
// now $children is alphabetized
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function taclinkch(x){var y=document.getElementById(x).value;document.location.href=y}</script>";
echo "<form action=''>  <select name='eventcats' id='eventcats'   onchange='taclinkch(this.id)'>";
  echo "<option value=''>Select a Topic</option>";
  foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child->term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    echo "<option value='" .  get_site_url() . "/events/category/". $term->slug." '>" . $term->name . "</option>";
  }
echo "</select></form>";
```

Comment: I realized orderby wouldn't work, but I wasn't sure how else to do it. Sorry to be simple, but where do I insert the code you provide into my original code?

Comment: This works, thank you. Would there be any reason why two of these drop-downs (one for location, one for topic) on the same page would conflict? The second one I add seems to become non-functional after the first use of either drop-down.

Comment: I'd have to see everything in context but that sounds like a Javascript issue. Check the console and check for invalid HTML.